# What range of unicode characters should be kept in a @font-face web font for a US based website with a US audience?

Tags: unicode, fonts

As part of optimizing a web development project, we need to strip out unnecessary characters that are never going to be used to reduce the size of font files. I have searched Google and found nothing canonical on the subject of which characters are required and which are safe to remove.

I've found the following ranges that may be of interest:

```
0020 — 007F     Basic Latin
00A0 — 00FF     Latin-1 Supplement
0100 — 017F     Latin Extended-A
0180 — 024F     Latin Extended-B
0250 — 02AF     IPA Extensions
02B0 — 02FF     Spacing Modifier Letters
0300 — 036F     Combining Diacritical Marks
27C0 — 27EF     Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-A
```

It seems that the most aggressive approach would be to only keep "Basic Latin", 0020 — 007F, which provides upper and lower-case letters, numbers and a few basic symbols, like the $, +, (, ), etc.

Latin-1 Supplement contains some extra goodies like Trademark and Copyright symbols and fractions.

Latin Extended-A and -B contain letters with accent marks, and since our copy is in English, I'm not sure if these will ever be needed.

If we use only that ranges (0020 — 007F) and (00A0 — 00FF), will we run into problems down the line with missing characters, should some user decide to post a comment in Spanish (for example)? Or will the browser fall back to a default font for characters that aren't included the web font?

The point of a web-font is to make the main bodies of text and headlines look pretty, which the basic latin set should cover, but I don't know if there are hidden "gotchas" with stripping down to just the "Basic Latin" range, like accented characters showing as diamond question marks instead of falling back to a system font, etc.

What range of unicode characters should be kept in a @font-face web
font for a US based website with a US audience? Are there any best practices or guidelines for striping unnecessary characters from a font for web use?

Comment: well, what's a "us audience"? If you mean "english only", then by all means strip out any characters that aren't used in standard US English. But note that things like `&eacute;` should probably be left in, otherwise some grammar nazi is going to tear you a new one when you site shows "Resume" instead of "Resumé"

Comment: @MarcB: how many Americans can spell "Résumé" correctly?

Comment: obviously not this canadian :p

Comment: That's a good point though. It looks like `&eacute;` is `00e9`, which still falls in the `Latin-1 Supplement` range.

Comment: This is a) primarily opinion-based, b) off-topic, since it is about the use of characters, something that you should have decided before addressing programming and site management issues, c) too vague, d) too broad (too many different questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend subsetting to one of the common "code page" definitions that support US/Western Europe. Most code page definitions pre-date Unicode and typically have the bits and pieces needed for various regional support without including entire Unicode blocks. Suggestions:

- [Windows Code Page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)
- [ISO/IEC 8859-1 "Latin 1"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)*
- [ISO/IEC 8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)

*This is the same as Unicode Ranges 0020-007F Basic Latin + 00A0-00FF Latin-1 Supplement

These include much more than is strictly *required* for US English, though as noted above, several accented characters commonly appear in English text (é, ñ, as well as other punctuation marks and symbols). These sets include those characters, so you should be in good shape for the vast majority of text for a U.S. audience. Note also that in most fonts, these characters are typically "composites", which means that they use a reference to the components (e.g. '**é**' is built from references to '**e**' and '**´**'); as such, they don't normally require as much size to store them, so retaining them usually won't incur a major size penalty.

If you might encounter European financial text, I'd suggest either Windows 1252 or ISO/IEC 8859-15 which include the Euro currency symbol.

Comment: ISO 8859-1 matches the Unicode range u+0000 to u+00ff, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Origin_and_development

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Edited answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if there are hidden "gotchas" with stripping down to just the "Basic Latin" range, like accented characters showing as diamond question marks instead of falling back to a system font

Any characters that don't exist in the font you are using will fall back to any default font the browser can find with the characters in. This will likely be ugly when interleaved with other characters from your custom font, but modern OSes provide decent font coverage for commonly-used characters from the above blocks so typically it will still be readable.

So you should include characters based on whether you think they'll be used commonly enough that having them rendered in an ugly font is a deal-breaker. For what it's worth, a pretty minimal set I have used before for a similar purpose is `¡£°±²³¿ÉËÑéëñ‘’“”–—•€™`, but your site's exactly requirements may vary. (For example, if you coöpted the New-Yorker-style diaeresis you would certainly want `äëïöü`.)

(How exactly default fallback fonts work varies between browsers and was famously troublesome in older versions of IE, and IE Mobile. But the basic accented Latin letters are pretty safe.)